# Worldbuilding forum or other conversational place?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources

**This Query is part of the Worldbuilding [Resources Article](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources).**

---

I recently posted a worldbuilding question on this stackexchange about a magic system I am trying to develop, and realize now that it would be better posted in a place like a forum, where the conversation could range back and forth down the thread.

So my new question is: Is there a very active worldbuilding forum or other conversational venue appropriate for a thread on developing a magic system for a fictional modern world?

Comment: I would recommend trying out the sub-reddit for worldbuilding. Please remember that in both this site and on reddit, its normal users offering you advice. They are not paid to do so, so don't go in expecting to post a question and getting back an amazing answer without working with the people who take the time to reply to you.

Comment: Shadowzee, I'm only looking for conversation, not my problems solved magically for me (pun intended, grin).

Comment: Cyn, I don't think I agree that asking for worldbuilding resource recommendations is not on topic, but if you are in charge here, I guess what you say goes. :)

Comment: @Sindyr The replies on reddit are more suitable to conversation and answers, so you might get your problem magically solved, but you can also have a proper discussion. You might also try the Chat rooms we have here (I don't know the link to it) or maybe try and find a discord for worldbuilders if you are just looking to chat.

Comment: @Shadowzee, thanks, I just posted on that subreddit, I hope for interesting discussion.

Comment: Worldbuilding Chat (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) is ideal for the kind of active debate that you're looking for. It's usually pretty quiet this time of the morning but participation varies

Comment: @Renan Ideally this could be placed into a Wiki or even as a comment/edit to the original question. I admit It does feel very suitable for the meta.

Comment: We allow questions asking for resources; we even have a tag for it.  How is this not on-topic for *main*?

Comment: Isn't it also a list question?

Comment: @TGar I don't believe so. OP is asking for ***a*** worldbuilding forum based on specific criteria (activity level, whether they deal with the development of magic systems). A list question would be asking for *every* worldbuilding forum, and would absolutely be off-topic as too broad.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many!

- **[CBB](https://cbbforum.com)** -- a discussion forum catering to invented languages & worlds
- **[Reddit Worldbuilding](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/)** -- general worldbuilding forum

  - [**Reddit Worldbuilding Discord**](https://discord.gg/worldbuilding) - - the subreddit's official discord-server
- **[Reddit Fantasy Worldbuilding](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyWorldbuilding/)** -- a narrow focus
- **[Reddit Fantasy Maps](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyMaps/)** -- fantasy cartography
- **[Reddit Fantasy Writers](https://www.reddit.com/r/fantasywriters/)** -- for writers
- **[ConWorlds](http://conworlds.fun/cwbb/index.php)** -- a general purpose worldbuilding discussion forum (defunct, posts still visible)
- **[GTX0](http://gtx0.com)** -- Currently defunct, but it has been known to rise from the ashes in the past
- **[ZBB](http://www.verduria.org/)** -- another general purpose invented language & culture forum

Those are the main ones, and there are certainly other highly specialised forums as well.

Comment: It occurs to me that maybe we should have a “reason to close” comment that has this list (or a link to this list) as its boiler plate text.

Comment: @SRM -- I am honoured to be considered as a reason for closure! ;)  Seriously, the question (and related questions) do come up from time to time, so there is a clear need. Whether the community thinks the need is great enough might best be left for a meta discussion. I'd suggest considering the aggregation of this kind of question (forums) along with questions of outside resources and perhaps some others. In the boiler plate text, just link to both answers. I'd have to look around for the resources answer...

Comment: @SRM -- [Here's one resource query.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/166426/what-fantasy-wordbuilding-tools-do-you-know-of-and-recommend)  and [here's another](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)

Comment: These should be added to the [list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/143607/40609)

Comment: @JBH -- Done & done! (Also updated some of the links in that resource.)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other suggestions you can always try worldbuilding's chat on this very website: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor

You're always welcome to discuss ideas and ask for suggestions there so long as you have the 20 rep needed to post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in fantasy worldbuilding, Mythic Scribes is an excellent place:
https://mythicscribes.com/community/