# When creating a fantasy nation, how deeply should I dive into it, and what parts aren't required to know?

Tags: society, magic, worldbuilding-process, military

I've been trying my hand at fantasy stories for close to five years now, but one thing that always throws me for a loop is CREATING THE WORLD. I realize it's a long slow process, and I've been making some notable progress in the past weeks, but there are some details that I don't know if I should be aware of, or if I can leave them out?

Most recently I've been flustered by the structure of military. How much time and effort should I devote to creating an army? How many troops does the nation have at its disposal, how many of said troops does it send out at a time, how many different branches does the military have, what types of soldiers and artillery are they made up of, all sorts of questions. The world I plan to build does include magic, but it's a relatively minor part of the while thing (regardless I think it could find a place in the midst of a legion). I'd really appreciate it if somebody could  clarify a good course of action for me.

Comment: Relevant: [Good Enough: How to Know When You're Done](https://medium.com/universe-factory/good-enough-how-to-know-when-you-re-done-7df1a16fedac).

Comment: Also, welcome to the site! Feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986) when you get a chance. Also also, [we have a blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4037/6986) (as I linked above) and you are welcome to wander its many pages.

Comment: Sorry, the question as it stands now cannot be answered: it all depends on your story and world. If you are making a world of Caribbean pirates you might skip laser invention, while for a Blade runneresque story you might want to deal with it.

Comment: While I agree that this is going to differ story by story, I think that there is a certain amount of help that can be given in thinking about it.  VTR.

Comment: First, why the magic tag? Meaning would the answer be related to the magic 
(like cooperative spells where # of users effects) or not? Second, what you are asking is part of the overall strategy (resources) that countries readily deal with today. See my [answer to building strategy and tactics questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/is-the-elementary-evil-vs-you-wights-rooting-henrys-troops-out-ready-for-re/7213#7213) for more details on how you could focus this question (currently there are so many issues to ask about it wouldn't be answerable using SE's model)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  As it turns out, [we have a list of world building resources that includes links to guides for military creation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/143607/40609).  You might want to give that a look-see!

Comment: This kind of discussion question is inappropriate for Stack Exchange, as I'm sure you've gathered by now!  It is however, entirely on topic for a more appropriate worldbuilding forum.  [Check out these possibles!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132660/worldbuilding-forum-or-other-conversational-place/132662#132662)

Comment: @JRAlderson Contrary to what **elemtilas** says, I do think this question has a place at Stack Exchange... just not here. Even if you are talking about world building, this is a *writing* question. Try at https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Our list of worldbuilding resources might help you, i know there is a link about Army creation (as i put it there), which might help you. It has links to various other pages about worldbuilding in general which might also help you: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources?