# What fantasy worldbuilding tools do you know of and recommend?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

First time participant here.

I'm in my research phase looking for world building tools that will help me build my world and product D&D quest modules. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Currently, I have found:

**D&D or d20 Campaign Writing Tool**

- Fantasy Grounds

**World Building Tool/Organizer**

- WordAnvil
- Apps Persona/Contour/Montage

**Map making tools or reference**

- The Magical Society: Guide to Map Making
- Incarnate
- Wonderdraft
- Campaign Cartographer

**Other Tools**

- Donjon
- Medieval City
- Tectonics
- Azgaar's Fantasy Map Gen
- Medieval City
- Dungeon Painter
- Illwinter's floor plan
- Mapforge

Anything else that is really a must-have to make things easier???

Comment: I'm sure this query will be closed because it's not exactly on-topic. Here, we actually help you build your world -- single focused query gets a single focused response -- as per the [tour] and [help]. Meta might be a better place to ask about resources. There are also [other forums](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132660/worldbuilding-forum-or-other-conversational-place/132662#132662) you could look into where conversational queries of this sort are more appropriate.

Comment: @elemtilas Asking for resources is on-topic here, but only for specific aspects of world-building. It looks like OP is asking specifically for map-making resources, as those are all they've listed, so if they could provide some information on exactly what it is they're looking for, then this would be a good question.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Fair enough, though not all the tools listed are map making per se. Quite a few are, though!

Comment: I am a new comer that is true - but if folks simply provide answers and don't converse, doesn't that fit the forum goal? I haven't asked for opinions, just tools. Seems pretty specific to me for a Worldbuilding forum. BUT....like I said, I am new so maybe my expectations are too broad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)

Comment: That list VLAZ, is probably exactly what I was looking for. Thank you EVERYONE for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately for you, we already have just such a list prepared! Just head over to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources) and take a look; just be careful you don't get overwhelmed by the sheer abundance of information there!

Answer (score 1):

As long as we're on the topic of mapmaking, I found that using the map editor for Civilization 5 was quite useful for the first draft of my map.  Because it draws in hex tiles, it very easily lends itself to drawing to a scale.  Just decide how big a single hex is, and your map will naturally be to scale.  No need to measure anything.

I then took a screenshot, and used that as a reference to help me redraw it in Inkarnate, to make it more aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution to your list of resources: [this short Questionnaire](http://www.bethisad.com/questionnaire.htm)! A general purpose worldbuilding questionnaire designed to get the creative juices flowing. It's not a recipe for building a culture, but rather is supposed to be an aid towards that end.